# How do I disable some dates on a DateTimePicker control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetimepicker

How can I disable selected dates in a `DateTimePicker` so that a user cannot select them? I know it's possible in Web Forms but in Windows Forms I'm unable to do this. How can I achieve this?

Comment: or any other components which supports this feature would be fine too

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172413/devexpress-dateedit-customization-to-allow-only-specific-dates

Answer (score 5):

The ease with which you can do this will depend on the dates you want to restrict. For instance, if you all you want to do is specify a range of valid dates to pick, then you can use the [MinDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.mindate.aspx) and [MaxDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.maxdate.aspx) properties to set the bounds.  If however, you want to cherry pick certain days within a range (for instance, no weekends), there is no built in method for doing this.

You could either find a third party control with this functionality, or you could try to hack it a bit by adding an event handler to the [ValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.valuechanged.aspx) event, and forcing the current date time to the last value (which you'd have to cache) if they user picked something that was illegal according to your business logic... but this is a less than ideal way to do it.