# How can i make some of the dates as non selectable in DateTimePicker

Tags: .net, winforms, datetimepicker

I would like to disable some date as non-selectable date from a DateTimePicker control in winforms.

The dates will be U.S holidays of every year and sunday's too.

I am not using any data base for my application.

So any idea please

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361691/how-do-i-disable-some-dates-on-a-datetimepicker-control