# Limiting the dates within a C# win form DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, .net, datetimepicker

Is it possible to limit which dates a user can select from a `dateTimePicker` on a C# winforms application?

The basic principle for me is this: I have a `comboBox` with 5 items in it, based on which item the user selects I would like to limit which dates the user can then select from, having the unavailable dates grayed out.

Is this possible?

Comment: So a user can type a date which is not present in Combo or he has to choose something from Combo only?

Comment: You might also want to look into [the `MonthCalendar` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9a9k6dd.aspx)

Comment: Yes something has to be selected, user can not enter there own data. So for example, if a user selects the first item, only 'Thursdays' are available to select from the dateTimePicker or monthCalender.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361691/how-do-i-disable-some-dates-on-a-datetimepicker-control

Comment: No answer so far has worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

Use the [`MinDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.mindate.aspx) and [`MaxDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.maxdate.aspx) properties.

```
dateTimePicker.MinDate = DateTime.Now;
dateTimePicker.MaxDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15);
```

[image: DateTimePicker]
(render on a french Windows 7)

Comment: I've set the properties to only display 1 calendar yet. So for example, if a user selects the first item in the comboBox, only 'Thursdays' are available to select from the dateTimePicker or monthCalender. Is this possible?

Comment: @user1077021: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361691/how-do-i-disable-some-dates-on-a-datetimepicker-control

Answer (score 1):

You can set a minimum and a maximum date for the C# WinForms DTP, so if thats what you wish to do, then you can use the `MinValue` and `MaxValue` variables. You can't pick and choose blocks of dates that are not allowed. This is something you would have to add yourself. There are 2 possible methods of doing this:

- Handing the ValueChanged event, then validate the date chosen.
- Inherit the DTP class and add some extra functionality in there.

Answer (score 1):

The `DateTimePicker` control has `MaxDate` and `MinDate` properties. Set those, and you can control the range of dates that can be selected.  Currently on my Windows XP with Windows Classic theme the unselectable dates do not appear grayed, but this may vary depending on operating system, theme, etc. If you absolutely *must* gray them, then you will have to subclass the DateTimePicker control and do the (or part of the) painting yourself.

Comment: Yes something has to be selected, user can not enter there own data. So for example, if a user selects the first item, only 'Thursdays' are available to select from the dateTimePicker or monthCalender.

Comment: This changes things a lot. You should have specified this in the question.  I am afraid you will have no option but to subclass the DateTimePicker control and handle the drawing yourself, because you are not talking about a single min-max range anymore, you are talking about multiple ranges. You will also have to perform the validation yourself: if the user selects a grayed date, you will need to prevent the control from dismissing itself. Okay -- you might not need to subclass the control, you might be able to get away by tapping on its events. But it is a considerable amount of work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at least MSDN says so. Refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the date restrictions in the following manner

```
dateTimePicker1.MinDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2);
dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(2);
```

In these case only the 5 available dates would be selectable for the user and the rest is not available. You could set up these values in the selectedindex changed event for the combobox and restrict it on the basis of your requirement/logic.