# DateTimePicker Should only show Current Date

Tags: c#, .net, datetimepicker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Limiting the dates within a C# win form DateTimePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353801/limiting-the-dates-within-a-c-sharp-win-form-datetimepicker)

in C#, is it possible to Only Set the DateTimePicker to the current date only? the users cannot select back to a previous or future dates. The DateTimePicker will only show or have the current Date.

Comment: And the current date is always __April 1__ ?

Comment: You should be able to do that setting the [MinDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.mindate.aspx) and [MaxDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.maxdate.aspx) properties. dateTimePicker1.MinDate = dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Now; According to some, this should actually throw a `DoesntMakeSenseException` , but... maybe it should be reported as a bug...

Comment: in my country is april 4, but anyway the date should be only like APril 4 2012. they cannot select other dates

Comment: @HenkHolterman. It's getting better! April 4. That's funny!

Comment: Why should they choose a date if they have only one option **?! ?! ?! ?!**

Comment: If you are trying to restrain the user to change date, just disable the datetimepicker for that instance ..and re-enable when you again want them to change

Comment: I'm trying to think what the DailyWTF article would be titled... "The `DateTimeNotPicker`"? "The `DateTimeCannotPicker`?

Comment: If you want only one value, why not disabling the control and fill the value yourself.  Giving the user an option that can be used leads to confusion.

Comment: Maybe he wants the user to just be able to pick the time part.

Comment: @JeremyP in that case, [How to: Display Time with the DateTimePicker Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229631.aspx)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to do that setting the [MinDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.mindate.aspx) and [MaxDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.maxdate.aspx) properties.

```
 dateTimePicker1.MinDate = dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Now;
```

According to some, this should actually throw a `DoesntMakeSenseException` , but...  maybe it should be reported as a bug...

Comment: No, the answer is just **WHY?** why do you want a datepicker letting  you pick only the current date...?

Comment: @gdoron , dude I'm just the messenger, don't pick on me.

Comment: LOL. I know it's not your brilliant idea... But I would at least mention that it doesn't make any sense!

Comment: Ok, I'm not in the mood of acting the doctor who says ".. .then stop doing that if it hurts" so... ;)

Comment: @gdoron I can think of few situations where someone would really wants to set the date to the current date in DateTimePicker.. Imagine if you want to limit a limited user from adding records in the past or the future? and your application checks if the user is limited then only let him add records for today, if the user is power user let him change the date to past!.. Or do you want to design two different forms, one for Limited users and one for Power users.. this is just one example..

Comment: @HaLaBi - If you want to limit the date to _today_, you don't offer a picker or even a UI. You simply use the date of today!

Comment: @Oded You are totally right, But maybe he is too confused to decide that.. and comments like gdoron's comments wont help..

Comment: @Oded if you have to keep the interface the same for UI reasons and only sometimes allow the user to change the date, you might want to still show the date picker, but make it unable to be changed in those cases where it can't be according to your design requirements.  Other times you might allow the change.  In both cases it is to the user's benefit to have the same interface.

Comment: @AdamDavis - If there is need to have a consistent UI, I agree. But then a _picker_ shouldn't be popping up and the control should have some sort of indication that it is disabled.

Comment: @oded that is one way of resolving the problem, and if that were the question asked it would be a good answer for it.