# Deactive specific day in Datetime picker c#

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I want to deactive the previous day of NOW, not from NOW to the future, but i can not find the way how to do it.
I use this code:

```
Datetimepicker1.Value = System.DateTime.Now;
Datetimepicker1.Enabled = false;
```

but it disable all day and i can not choose the day of future.

And the same question with deactive the next days of NOW, not from past to NOW.
Can anybody help me, thanks.

Comment: And setting [`MinDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.mindate.aspx) to `DateTime.Now` doesn't work?

Comment: Dupe I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353801/limiting-the-dates-within-a-c-sharp-win-form-datetimepicker

Answer (score 6):

You are disabling entire `DatePicker` control. What you need is setting [`MinDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.mindate.aspx) property on it:

```
dateTimePicker1.MinDate = DateTime.Now;
```