# How to color date in dateTimePicker C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a question about dateTimePicker. can I color the selected dates? I have date base with two dates. I want color this dates like calender with reservation. Is it possible in c# dateTimePicker?

Comment: There is no built in way to do that. Even for a month calendar it's not possible

Comment: You can search for a better UI control or a library on google, codeproject or github for example. What of sort of control do you want ? Simple like the standard or some advanced with more options?

Comment: Or change to WPF, winform is growing old.

Comment: DateTimePicker has no "selected dates", you are possibly talking about the calendar you see when you click the drop-down arrow.  Same gadget as the one provided by MonthCalendar.  It provides no option to colorize dates, it however can display them in bold type.  Getting a reference to this drop-down is the hard part, the subject of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36211949/17034).  But surely you'd prefer the [simple solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8353860/17034).

Comment: I would suggest create your own Datetime control using a tablelayoutpanel. It is not that difficult to do so