# How can I limit DatetimePicker in windows form c#?

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

**I have two datetimePickers in my form**.

- First Start date.
- Second End Date.

I want to limit second datetimepicker to the end of the month of the year.
If we are in 2020, its range should be till 31.12.2020.

```
private void DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dateTimePicker1.MinDate=?
        }
```

Comment: _to the end of the month of the year_ I'm sorry I don't understand that. Today it would go until 31.12.2020 right? In august would it go to 31.08.2020 or also to 31.12.2020?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limiting the dates within a C# win form DateTimePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353801/limiting-the-dates-within-a-c-sharp-win-form-datetimepicker)

Comment: yes, If we are in 2021, it should calculate that to the end of the year. Current date is 2019 now, so we can choose it till 31 december.

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this. **There is no special event for setting the MaxDate you set it once you create an instance of DateTimePicker.**

Also you should be setting datepicker's`MaxDate` property not `MinDate`

```
DateTimePicker dateTimePicker2 = new DateTimePicker();

// Set the MaxDate.
dateTimePicker2.MaxDate= new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,12,31);
```

DateTimePicker has a Value Changed event which is called once you change any dates on the datepicker

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
var maxDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,12,31);
```

Comment: are you using winform ?

Comment: yes. But this code did not work. I can stil select other dates. Did you clearly get my point? it must be calculated from your current time. for example it`s 2019 now. I want user not able to choose higher values than the end of the day of the year which is 2019, Dec31. If we were in 2023, 2024 or sth like that, user wouldnt be able choose end date higher that its year day of the month

Comment: Bacause you are setting the MinDate here, You have to set the MaxDate property for this to take effect