# DevExpress dateedit customization to allow only specific dates

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, devexpress, .net-2.0

I have used the example here [How to create a DateEdit descendant that will allow date unit selection, and multiple dates and periods selection](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E2007?currentProgrammingLanguage=VB.NET&version=v2009%20vol%202.9%20-%20v2012%20vol%201.9). I wanted to add one more functionality where I would provide an array of dates only those will be visible. I have modified the code and included a property to accept the date ranges, which if provided would only allow seeing and selecting those dates, but I'm unable to understand which function I should override to accomplish the task. The behavior should be like when the editor is supplied `MaxValue` and `MinValue`

[Here is my code](http://pastebin.com/jcbyYeXS)

Comment: Have you asked the guys from DevExpress ? They are very helpful about thise sort of things.

Comment: I think they are following this post in SO.

Comment: @JensKloster is right. Whenever it comes to Devexpress, it's always best to ask them directly. You will generally get the answer within the next 24 hours, which is usually faster than SO, especially for such complex (too localized) questions as this one.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the (standard) implementation of the VistaDateEditInfoArgs class. You may use a .NET assembly decompiler like .NET Reflector or ILSpy.
There are a couple of virtual methods you may override and return null if the related datetime should not be visible/allowed.
Here is the source code of these methods (please note the "standard" MinValue / MaxValue based checks) :

**[DevExpress.XtraEditors.ViewInfo.VistaDateEditInfoArgs]**

```
protected virtual DayNumberCellInfo CreateMonthCellInfo(int row, int col)
{
    DayNumberCellInfo info;
    DateTime date = new DateTime(this.DateTime.Year, (1 + (row * 4)) + col, 1);
    if (date > this.Calendar.MaxValue)
    {
        return null;
    }
    if ((date < this.Calendar.MinValue) && (date.Month < this.Calendar.MinValue.Month))
    {
        return null;
    }

    return new DayNumberCellInfo(date) { Text = this.Calendar.DateFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName    (info.Date.Month) };
}

protected virtual DayNumberCellInfo CreateYearCellInfo(int row, int col)
{
    int num = ((this.DateTime.Year / 10) * 10) - 1;
    int year = (num + (row * 4)) + col;
    if ((year <= 0) || (year >= 0x2710))
    {
        return null;
    }
    DateTime date = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
    if (date > this.Calendar.MaxValue)
    {
        return null;
    }
    if ((date < this.Calendar.MinValue) && (date.Year < this.Calendar.MinValue.Year))
    {
        return null;
    }
    DayNumberCellInfo info = new DayNumberCellInfo(date) {
        Text = year.ToString()
    };
    if ((year < ((this.DateTime.Year / 10) * 10)) || (year > (((this.DateTime.Year / 10) * 10) + 1)))
    {
        info.State = ObjectState.Disabled;
    }
    return info;
}

protected virtual DayNumberCellInfo CreateYearsGroupCellInfo(int row, int col)
{
    int num = ((this.DateTime.Year / 100) * 100) - 10;
    int year = num + (((row * 4) + col) * 10);
    if ((year < 0) || (year >= 0x2710))
    {
        return null;
    }
    int num3 = year + 9;
    if (year == 0)
    {
        year = 1;
    }
    DateTime date = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
    if (date > this.Calendar.MaxValue)
    {
        return null;
    }
    if ((date < this.Calendar.MinValue) && (num3 < this.Calendar.MinValue.Year))
    {
        return null;
    }
    return new DayNumberCellInfo(date) { Text = year.ToString() + "-\n" + num3.ToString() };
}
```

I suggest you to override these methods in your descendant class and add your custom checks. For example, you may override the CreateMonthCellInfo method somehow like this:

```
protected override DayNumberCellInfo CreateMonthCellInfo(int row, int col)
{
    DateTime date = new DateTime(this.DateTime.Year, (1 + (row * 4)) + col, 1);

    if (!IsDateAvailable(date))
    {
        return null;
    }

    return base.CreateMonthCellInfo(row, col);
}

// Your date availibility check implementation here
private bool IsDateAvailable(DateTime date)
{
    // TODO provide implementation
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: The method `CreateMonthCellInfo` is not even firing. Only `CreateDayCell` is firing and If I put the same logic in the `CreateDayCell` method an exception is arising.