# Disable some dates in datetimepicker winform c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to disable some dates into DateTimePicker, is it possible?
For example, I have a dates range: { 20/12/2014, 21/12/2014, 22/12/2014, 23/12/2014, 24/12/2014 }
I need to disable the midle one or in others situations the last one, can anybody help me?

The dateTimePicker1.MainDate and dateTimePicker1.MaxDate is not enough.

Thank you.

Comment: While it is a bit more work, [Piotr Wolkowski's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27319756/3191303) is a decent approach using pure .Net. Otherwise @Anthony found a useful link for you as well.

Comment: This question shouldn't be marked as duplicate. The question they are referring has low quality accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from .Net 4 it is possible in WPF. You can then host the WPF `datepicker` inside a Winforms app. An example (from MSDN) to disable Saturdays and Sundays:

```
DatePicker datePickerWithBlackoutDates = new DatePicker();

datePickerWithBlackoutDates.DisplayDateStart = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1);
datePickerWithBlackoutDates.DisplayDateEnd = new DateTime(2009, 8, 31);
datePickerWithBlackoutDates.SelectedDate = new DateTime(2009, 8, 10);

datePickerWithBlackoutDates.BlackoutDates.Add(
    new CalendarDateRange(new DateTime(2009, 8, 1), new DateTime(2009, 8, 2)));
datePickerWithBlackoutDates.BlackoutDates.Add(
    new CalendarDateRange(new DateTime(2009, 8, 8), new DateTime(2009, 8, 9)));
datePickerWithBlackoutDates.BlackoutDates.Add(
    new CalendarDateRange(new DateTime(2009, 8, 15), new DateTime(2009, 8, 16)));
datePickerWithBlackoutDates.BlackoutDates.Add(
    new CalendarDateRange(new DateTime(2009, 8, 22), new DateTime(2009, 8, 23)));
datePickerWithBlackoutDates.BlackoutDates.Add(
    new CalendarDateRange(new DateTime(2009, 8, 29), new DateTime(2009, 8, 30)));

datePickerWithBlackoutDates.DateValidationError +=
new EventHandler<DatePickerDateValidationErrorEventArgs>(DatePicker_DateValidationError);
```

More details on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

I haven't seen anything similar that would be specifically for Winforms though. As a workaround you can port this WPF component into Winforms app.

Here's MSDN resource on **interopeartion of WPF and Winforms**:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751797(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I was just going to downvote this, since the OP intends this to be used in WinForms, but the power of Google compels me to upvote you. [Use WPF controls in WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: There is a link added in the post to a tutorial how to do that. Just in case I'll make it bit more visible.

Comment: That link appears to be broken ...

Comment: @MikeHoney I replaced it with an MSDN resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a max date, but you cannot selectively disable arbitrary dates in the valid range.

Please see [How do I disable some dates on a DateTimePicker control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361691/how-do-i-disable-some-dates-on-a-datetimepicker-control)