# Customize winforms calendar control

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, calendar

In the system I'm doing , I need a calendar that has only the weekends of each month enabled to be selected , the rest is off ..

How can I do this in C # Winforms ?

I researched on the internet and here at the Forum and found nothing exactly like that, I found some things but I could not do what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcomee to stackoverflow,

This option is not available within the current tools. You could go and make a custom control by  making a custom DateTimePicker inherited from the standard one. I never done this but [this might get you started.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258770/My-first-Net-Component-is-DateTimePicker-that-acce) or you might be able to [do something with this article.](http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/a-custom-datetimepicker-control-in-c.70925/)

If you don't want to go into custom Controls which will make you spend a lot of time, you could just do something like this:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

  var dtp = sender as DateTimePicker;

  var selectedDate = dtp.Value;

  if (!(selectedDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || selectedDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday))
  {

    var offset = (int)DayOfWeek.Saturday - (int)selectedDate.DayOfWeek;

    var saturday = selectedDate + TimeSpan.FromDays(offset);

    dtp.Value = saturday;

    label1.Text = "only saturday or sunday please";

  }
```

}

and prompt the user with a label message telling him that it has been changed.

Comment: Very good man , but he's not letting select Sundays , Saturdays only . I need only the weekends ( Saturday and Sunday ) .

I thought I could leave other dates ashes for example, or not Selectable .

But that way this very good

Comment: If it's the correct answer than you could mark this one as accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, it's the correct answer, but he's not letting select Sundays , Saturdays only . I need only the weekends ( Saturday and Sunday ) :s   .can you help me,please?

Comment: So using this code you can only choose Saturday now? When you choose Sunday it still jumps to Saturday?

Comment: So with this code only I can choose Saturday.

When I select Sunday jumps to Saturday .

Comment: I see my error, it's updated, check the if statement

Comment: Now this perfect. Thanks ever so much...I’m very grateful to you for helping me.. :D

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific control in Winforms. Easiest workaround is to use a WPF control and then a Winforms host for WPF control. You can find some details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27319756/3330348