# Disable unwanted dates in date picker in c# window application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to be able to just disable the dates  in date picker in c# windows application  I.e. I want all dates to show in the control but to either A) Highlight the ones that are available to select or B) gray out the ones that are not available to select.  ?    Thank you

Comment: Maybe this could help you [Limit Dates in a DatePicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353801/limiting-the-dates-within-a-c-sharp-win-form-datetimepicker) , note that  with Max and Min properties you can choose a continuous range for available dates.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but i don't want the date range. ie. I want just the 12, 13, 15, and 16th to be available for selection, but not the 14th. (14 th shows in grey color. and other dates highlighted)

Comment: @Minu: WPF or WinForms?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment, if you want 12-16 available dates, you can:

1.- Limit your available datos for the range 12 to 16, as done here: [Limit Dates in a DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353801/limiting-the-dates-within-a-c-sharp-win-form-datetimepicker)

+Plus

2.- Using [BlackoutDates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.blackoutdates%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), insert 14th as a forbidden date: "datePickerWithBlackoutDates" should be replaced for your DatePicker name.

```
DatePicker datePickerWithBlackoutDates = new DatePicker();

datePickerWithBlackoutDates.DisplayDateStart = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1);
datePickerWithBlackoutDates.DisplayDateEnd = new DateTime(2009, 8, 31);
datePickerWithBlackoutDates.SelectedDate = new DateTime(2009, 8, 10);

datePickerWithBlackoutDates.BlackoutDates.Add(
new CalendarDateRange(new DateTime(2009, 8, 14), new DateTime(2009, 8, 14)));
```

**UPDATE**

Since you're using winforms, there's already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27319417/disable-some-dates-in-datetimepicker-winform-c-sharp) about it. The solution purposed is the same, using WPF inside winforms.

However, there're a link to [controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361691/how-do-i-disable-some-dates-on-a-datetimepicker-control), where you can find new controls, and they said that `DateEdit` could be used for your purpose.

Comment: You are are using WPF. I suspect the OP is using winforms.

Comment: sir ,i am beginner in c# window application... that's y i am asking is it possible in c# window application.. it shows an error datepicker namespace not found.not wpf

Comment: i am using winforms.. not WPF

Comment: Updated with something more about it. In fact, it's a duplicate question.

Comment: You're welcome, just say us if this worked for you. If then, mark the answer as correct ;)