# disabled days before today in datetimepicker C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to disable (not hide) days before today in DateTimePicker

I wrote this code:

```
dtpFromDate.MinDate = DateTime.Now;
```

It did not disable the dates but hid them.

Comment: @o_O it didn't work with me

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27319417/disable-some-dates-in-datetimepicker-winform-c-sharp)

Comment: This is not possible with the standard `DateTimePicker` control. You'd have to subclass it and fix this yourself or use a third party control that supports this.

Comment: You can try to override Drawing and Editing of you `DateTimePicker` control.

Comment: can you show the html code generated? you can use Jquery to remove or disable the buttons on document ready

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable some dates on a DateTimePicker control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361691/how-do-i-disable-some-dates-on-a-datetimepicker-control)

Comment: I'm using winForm not asp.net

Comment: @o_O I haven't 'DisplayDateStart' So i didn't work with me

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with the `DateTimePicker`-control, like already stated in comments.

As a workaround you can check the date inside the `Validating`-event:

```
private void dtpFromDate_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (dtpFromDate.Value < DateTime.Today)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You can't choose this date!");
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You **can't** disable it. Like this you can't leave the `DateTimePicker`-control with any value before today. If you want, you can remove the MessageBox, then no message is shown, but the user does not know why.

Comment: Yes, you can select it, but you can't **leave** the DateTimePicker.