# disable some date in date picker

Tags: c#, datepicker

hi i have a datepicker in my winforms and i want to disable the date exists in my dataBase?

```
num_reglement = date_paiement.Text + "-" + txtMatricule.Text;
                    paiement save_paiement = new paiement(num_reglement, double.Parse(txtmontantht.Text),
                            cmb_paiement.Text, txtbanque.Text, txt_cheque.Text,
                            date_paiement.Value.Date.ToShortDateString(), txtMatricule.Text, txtlibelle.Text);

            save_paiement.insert();
```

Comment: do you know what you are asking here ? because i didn't understand what you want to do

Comment: i have a datepicker and i have some date save in datebase i want to disable this date saved in datepicker. for example if i have 28/12/2015 in table invoice of database the datepicker must disable this date and if haven't  the date 27/12/2015 in table invoice of database the datepicker must enable that. you understand me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable some dates on a DateTimePicker control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361691/how-do-i-disable-some-dates-on-a-datetimepicker-control)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think date time Picker has any such property. It has Max-Date, Min-Date property if you have valid date range, if you want to validate from database ,Only way is to check in Text changed event if value exits in database and show popup of rejection.Otherwise use some third party Control.