# How to enable a specific week day in DateTimePicker C# according to the day number(0,1,2,…,6) and disable the other days?

Tags: c#, datetimepicker, windows

I'm creating a windows form application C#,
I'm trying to disable all weekdays in DateTimePicker C#  and keep one day on and not disabled according to the day number that i write in the Textbox "day_toselect".

Notice about day number :
Sunday is day 0, Monday is day 1 ,..., Wednesday is day 3, .....Saturday is day 6.

FOR EXAMPLE : if I write 3 in the Textbox named "day_toselect", so i want only to turn on all Wednesdays in the DateTimePicker and disable all the other days.

Is there a way to do that?

My code is:

```
calend_App.FirstDayOfWeek = int.Parse(day_toselect.Text.toString());
```

I know that this is totaly a wrong code, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: There are multiple questions about this on StackOverflow. Have none of them popped up while you were writing the question? There is no built-in way to do it in winforms, though some answers offer workarounds and suggestions.

Comment: i didn't find anything that  works for me on winforms!

Comment: all is about asp.net not windows form

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361691 and see the linked questions there. Or even related questions on this very page.

Comment: are you sure you want to make the days of the week start at 0? 0 makes sense to programmers, but a general user might not understand that very well.

Comment: @BlakeThingstad i didn't say i want them to start at 0, i said if day number is 0, so sunday is activated and the others are disabled, ....

Comment: @HasanHajjar that's what I said too except I'm suggesting maybe Sunday is 1, Monday is 2, ..., Saturday is 7

Comment: yeah i know, but how to do it? is there a way to solve my problem?! I didn't find anything.